# Adding a separator line under custom tableview cell in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a separator to my uitableview cell. i tried this.

```
let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 8.0))
cell.contentView.addSubview(separator)
```

But this adds the separator view on top of the cell, i need it to the bottom.

I also tried this way.

```
let view = UIView()
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8.0).isActive = true
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

But this gives me no common ancestor error. and i don't want to use storyboard. i need it because i am using same cell at different places, somewhere i need the separator somewhere not. what should i do?

Comment: Why don't you add it in the interface itself?

Comment: You can use XIB to design your cell and re use it wherever necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Change constraint for this

```
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

to

```
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

its better to create the line inside init of the custom cell and make it a property

```
let view = UIView()
```

then mange its state from `cellForRowAt`

```
view.isHidden = true/false
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to use separators:

First enable separators in your `UITableView` by:

```
myTableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
```

Then at your `cellForRowAt` function:

```
// Create your cell
// if you want to show the separator then 
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
// if you want to hide the separator then
self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

This would work for cells in the same UITableView as well. Because by adding a left inset of screen width then it won't show on screen and if you set it to 0 it'll be displyed from left edge to right edge of the screen.

Also you can change the color or the insets of the separator by using other properties without using storyboards or xibs.

Comment: I wan trying to use a custom separator.

Answer (score 1):

you can just try below line under viewDidLoad() that include the tableview

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     
    tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
}
```